# C++ - RapidJSON has no member Writer

Tags: c++, rapidjson

Im using this snippet of code to stringify a dom with rapidjson:

```
rapidjson::StringBuffer buffer;
rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
document.Accept(writer);
```

But i get the error that Writer is not a member of the rapidjson namespace.

My includes are:

```
 #include "rapidjson/document.h"
 #include "rapidjson/writer.h"
 #include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
 #include <iostream>
```

as mentioned in the example simpledom.cpp.

So my question is if this is a bug or does it need another writer class for this?
Did i miss any includes? I use the latest version of rapidjson.

Comment: Weird, does it change anything if you write `using namespace rapidjson;` at the top? I.e. you pollute the global namespace

Comment: hey, i also tried it with the global namespace, but it didnt work either. I use VS2012 as editor. Maybe it's just an error VS is throwing. I didn't try to compile it yet.

Comment: Try to compile, that might be related to intellisense

Comment: when i try to compile it i get the error, that RAPIDJSON_UINT64_C2 is not defined in dtoa.h several times. an other errors related to writer.h.

Comment: Well i switched to an older version now (0.11) obtained from here: https://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/downloads/detail?name=rapidjson-0.11.zip and everything works fine right now. First version i have used was from github: https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson

Comment: Not sure but it might be a bug. Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to an older version (0.11) https://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/downloads/detail?name=rapidjson-0.11.zip and the error didnt show up anymore.

The first version i have used was from github: https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson

Im not sure if the error was related to my dev environment or a bug in rapidjson.

Answer (score 0):

It is a late response but I think it would help other people who come here. In place of Writer<StringBuffer>
you code use PrettyWriter<StringBuffer>

after including prettywriter.h, of course.